# How do I access other IPv6 Adresses from my vps

Tags: node.js, ipv6, vps

## Hello StackOverflow!

I recently bought a VPS, where I was given 64 IPv6 addresses, however I find myself unable to use any of them except `:1`. The IPv6 gateway looks like this (masked with `x` for security reasons) `xxxx:xxxx:x:xxx::a` where `a` is 1 to 64, I should have all of them available to my service, I'm just not able to use any of them except 1. It says that 1 is automatically assigned to the OS installed on my VPS, does that mean I have to assign the rest of the addresses as well? If so, how do I do that?

Here's the code I used in Node.js to try this.

```
const Express = require("express");
const App = Express();
App.use(Express.static(__dirname+"/www"));
const Listener = App.listen(1024, "xxxx:xxxx:x:x:xx::2", () => {
        const addr = Listener.address();
        console.log("Listening on " + addr.address + ":" + addr.port);
});
```

The error that I get when I'm starting it is:

```
Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL xxxxx:xxxx:x:x:xx::2:1024
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1318:19)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1383:12)
    at doListen (net.js:1509:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:745:11)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:236:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:560:3)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1362:8)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
    [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:560:3)
```

Comment: Just because your VPS provider made those addresses available to you doesn’t mean that they configured your VPS to use them. Check with the OS tools and/or your VPS control panel to see if they’re actually assigned to the machine in question.

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS, how would I check it? (Sorry, I know I'm really stupid when it comes to this)

Comment: Command line tool ifconfig will tell you what interfaces the machine has and what IPs are assigned. I don’t know which VPS provider you have but for example Amazon also has a web console that will show (and let you change) bound IPs.  All that said, 64 addresses for one box seems like a lot, are you sure this is the path you need to go down?  Unless it’s a virtual router or switch, you shouldn’t have that many unique network interfaces.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that those 64 addresses are (or should) be available for me, here's a screenshot https://ibb.co/f3rX48 I'll try ifconfig and see what's there

Comment: Again “available to you” isn’t the same as “assigned to the virtual machine”. It’s like a dinner reservation. You can call and reserve a table, and it’s available to you, but until you show up and sit down, no seat is assigned to your buttocks. ;)

Comment: This is the the only one I had connected as well as lo of course https://ibb.co/mXpc48

Answer (score 0):

## Hello!

I managed to resolve this on my own after finding the right keywords to google for with the help of @Paul

The solution was to add each address to the interfaces file.

I used the command:

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 inet6 add xxxx:xxxx:x:x:xx::a/64
```